"Preview Node" shortcut not working
Ever since installing the newest Blender version (4.2.0 / 4.2.1), the "Preview Node" shortcut (Shift Ctrl LMB) in the editor no longer works. The issue has persisted even after completely uninstalling and reinstalling the program. Likewise, disabling and reenabling Node Wrangler does not help either.
Upon investigating the keybind settings, I discovered these strangely named binds (marked in red), which do not exist in 4.1.X, while the "Preview Node" keybind is nowhere to be found. Disabling either of these binds does nothing to alleviate the issue.

Quickly previewing node outputs from within the tree is an essential part of my workflow, so this has been quite the annoyance and has kept me from fully switching to the new version, so a fix would be greatly appreciated.

Is the Node Wrangler addon enabled?

It is. Luckily, I was now able to fix the issue based on a response below; I have detailed the process there for posterity.

From your screenshot, I see that some no-name "NODE_OT_nw_preview_node" overrides the actual "Link Viewer" shortcut, that you have described. So you should delete these two shortcuts (that you have encircled), or try Restore button, should delete them for you.

Unfortunately, I have already attempted this multiple times and it does not help.
Generally, the "Link Viewer" and "Preview Node" shortcuts are similar, but not quite identical and I would technically prefer the "Preview Node" shortcut. However, in the current state, neither of them work.

Well, look at your screenshot. Select (Extend) also has Shift+Ctrl+Left mouse, so it should override everything below with the same keys. If you have problems like this, I recommend you load factory settings, to get correct keymaps.

I tried a few things based on your response and found a solution:
I copied the "Connect to Output" command from the factory settings and inserted it into the broken keybinds. Then, "Select (Toggle)" (under "Node Tool: Select Box) was indeed overwriting the Shift Ctrl LMB command.
So in the end, it turned out to be a combination of two factors. The issue is now fixed, however. Thank you very much for the assistance!

Terribly sorry, but I have to retract my previous statement. The issue has now gotten even more perplexing.
The process I described I above does indeed solve the issue, but only for the current Blender session. Upon closing and reopening Blender, the issue returns. Switching to factory settings and then back to my key layout (without touching a single keybind, mind), fixes it again until a new file/window/session is opened.
I am not even sure how this happens, since preferences and keybinds are not file-specific, but saved globally.

Settings are stored in start up file. Try Defaults -> Save start up file. Or save preferences in preferences window.

That does not work either, unfortunately.
